# React Native is unable to find Android Module

Tags: android, react-native

I have created a react native library and I'm trying to test it using npm pack, and by installing tgz in my example application. But when I try to run my application I get an error:

```
Project with path ':MySDK' could not be found in project ':react-native- 
 my-sdk'
```

I'm exporting some native functionality in my library and it is packed in aar named MySDK.aar, I have imported it to my library with:
File->New->New->New Module->Import aar package.
The project builds fine in Android Studio and I'm able to access aar classes and methods, it only fails in react.
Here is build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    implementation project(':MySDK')
}
```

And build.gradle of MySDK module generated by Android Studio:

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('MySDK.aar'))
```

And also settings.gradle :

```
include ':MySDK'
```